# Materialize implementation within package

Tags: scala, scala-macros

When using a macro to materialize an implementation of a trait, I'd like to create the implementation within a package so that it has access to other package-private classes.

```
trait MyTrait[T]

object MyTrait {
  implicit def materialize[T]: MyTrait[T] = macro materializeImpl[T]

  def materializeImpl[T : c.WeakTypeTag](c: blackbox.Context): c.Expr[MyTrait[T]] = {
    val tt = weakTypeTag[T]
    c.Expr[MyTrait[T]](q"new MyTrait[$tt] {}")
  }
}
```

Is it possible to materialize `new MyTrait[$tt] {}` within a particular package?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A macro has to expand into an AST which would compile in the place the macro call is in. Since `package` declarations [are only allowed at top-level](https://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.11/09-top-level-definitions.html#packagings), and method calls aren't allowed there, the expanded tree can't create anything in another package.

Comment: In his thesis Eugene Burmako recalls top-level definitions in extensions of macros: https://infoscience.epfl.ch/record/226166/files/EPFL_TH7159.pdf (p. 116-117, 122)

Comment: Yes, I should have specified "a def macro", since that's what the question asks for.

Comment: I think this makes sense. Thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 0):

As Alexey Romanov pointed out this is not possible directly. Still if you call only a few methods (and if you use macro, most probably this is so), one possible (but not perfect) workaround might be creating a public abstract class or trait that extends the target trait and "publishes" all the required package private  methods as `protected` proxies. So you can create instances in your macro from inheriting from that abstract class rather than trait. Obviously this trick effectively "leaks" those methods to anyone but thanks to reflection anyone can call any method if he really wants. And abusing this trick will show as deliberate effort to circumvent your separation as the usage of the reflection.

Comment: I have a solution like this implemented now - thanks for the ratification though :)